# mongoDB Not Returning Query When Trying to Filter By Date

Tags: mongodb, momentjs

I am trying to find all documents that are created greater than or equal to a month ago.

But when I query the DB it returns nothing when doing the following code:

```
     console.log(moment().add(-31, "days").toDate()) // this logs 2022-09-30T07:27:26.373Z

                let filter = {
                    companyId: companyId,
                    userId: userId,
                    _created_at: {$gte: moment().add(-31, "days").toDate()}
                };

   db.collection("Users")
                    .find(filter)
                    .count()
                    .then(count => {
                        if(!count){
                            return resolve({result: [], count: 0});
                        } else {
                            db.collection("Users")
                                .find(filter)
                                .sort({_created_at: -1})
                                .limit(parseInt(limit))
                                .skip(parseInt(page) * parseInt(limit))
                                .toArray()
                                .then(result => {
                                    resolve({result: result, count: count});
                                })
                                .catch(error => {
                                    console.log(error);
                                    reject(error);
                                })
                        }
                    });
```

However when I do the following filter it works and returns the documents:

```
 let filter = {
                    companyId: companyId,
                    userId: userId,
                    _created_at: {$gte: moment().add(-31, "days").format("YYYY-MM-DD[T]HH:mm:ss.SSS[Z]") }
                };
```

The only thing i changed is the format of the date and i am specifiying exactly how it should be formatted to equal the DB but i do not want to do something hard coded. Although the moment().add(-31, "days").toDate() matches the same format in my DB.

Why am i not getting any results from the query?

Comment: That's the wrong way of doing it. Date values should be **never** stored as strings, it's a design flaw. Store always proper `Date` objects. Then `{$gte: moment().add(-31, "days").toDate()}` will work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`toDate()`](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/as-javascript-date/) returns a JS Date object, try with `format()` to return an ISO formatted date:

```
let filter = {
  companyId: companyId,
  userId: userId,
  _created_at: { $gte: moment().add(-31, 'days').format() },
};
```